# how to set a range of defaults in a count query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a simple table of values:

```
column1
-------
   2
   5
   7
   5
   8
   7
```

and this simple query of number count:

```
SELECT column1, count(column1) as counter
FROM table
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY count(column1) DESC
```

The question how can I add rows with values 0 when I have a number range for example from 1 to 8.
I want to get the result like this:

```
column1   Counter
--------  -------
   5         2
   7         2
   2         1
   8         1
   1         0   <-- Row Add
   2         0   <-- Row Add 
   3         0   <-- Row Add
   4         0   <-- Row Add
   6         0   <-- Row Add
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Very hard to do in MS Access.  Perhaps you should upgrade to another database or do this in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use more than 1 query and to put your range of numbers in a table at least temporarily then you can do this with a full outer join.  To do a Full outer join in access you combine a left join and a right join using either UNION OR UNION ALL.

[image]

[image]

copy the sql from the right and left joins into a union query then add the union and the order by statements to the union query.

```
SELECT SpecialNumbers.Numbers, mytable.Column1, Count(mytable.Column1) AS CountOfColumn1
FROM SpecialNumbers LEFT JOIN mytable ON SpecialNumbers.Numbers = mytable.Column1
GROUP BY SpecialNumbers.Numbers, mytable.Column1
UNION
SELECT SpecialNumbers.Numbers, mytable.Column1, Count(mytable.Column1) AS CountOfColumn1
FROM SpecialNumbers RIGHT JOIN mytable ON SpecialNumbers.Numbers = mytable.Column1
GROUP BY SpecialNumbers.Numbers, mytable.Column1
ORDER BY CountOfColumn1 DESC;
```

Given my special numbers where 1 to 10 This turns

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: And if you don't know in advance how many numbers you are going to need, it may be worth creating a small VBA procedure that deletes the values from SpecialNumbers, and then does a loop from 1 to MAX(value from myTable) to add the required numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much - mazoula, it is a good idea and how can I make it count appearances in 3 columns UNION to table SpecialNumbers

Comment: if no other changes are needed just add counts of those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only wish the four missing rows added, this is not that difficult in Access, as it is easy to create a small query generating numbers from a system table:

```sql
SELECT 
    T.Column1, 
    Count(Table.[Column1]) AS [Counter]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS Column1
    FROM MSysObjects
    WHERE (Abs([id] Mod 10)) Between 1 And 8) As T
LEFT JOIN 
    [Table] 
    ON T.Column1 = Table.Column1
GROUP BY 
    T.Column1
ORDER BY 
    Count(Table.[Column1]) DESC, 
    T.Column1;
```

Output:

[image]